# Would an ally get an Opportunity Attack if I were to knock an enemy towards them?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, opportunity-attack, forced-movement

Coming Sunday a party member and myself will be facing off against a wizard/warlock and some cultists.

The session last week ended on the Paladin initiating combat by jumping towards the warlock by surprise. (something I would've preferred to avoid before diplomacy had occurred but alas)

Now I was wondering, if I were to use the surprise to move towards the warlock without triggering Opportunity Attacks from the cultists, and I were to place myself in such a way that the Warlock was in between myself and the Paladin.

Upon using Thunderwave and the Warlock failing his saving throw (thus being knocked back), would our Paladin get an Opportunity Attack from the Warlock being knocked into his range? Or is this something that is entirely up to the DM?

I am an Evoker wizard so with Sculpt Spell I can protect the Paladin from my evocation spells.

Comment: Does the paladin have the Polearm Master feat? Getting closer to someone does not generally provoke an AoO.

Comment: He does not, pretty sure he went with the ability score increase

Comment: I appreciate that people take the time to help people with grammar and spelling. But changing every mention of 'attack of opportunity' to 'opportunity attack' for the sake of "proper terminology" was uncalled for. 'Attack of opportunity' is just as much the proper term as 'opportunity attack

Comment: @Bwash that is the proper term in 5e. I see nothing wrong with that. It is always better to use the right terms.

Comment: Also, there are no surprise rounds in 5e. Only surprised creatures that can't act in the first round of combat.

Comment: 1. regardless of terminology anyone familiar with D&D would know what I was talking about when I use the term "Attack of Opportunity"
it's not like I used completely unrelated words.
2. That's true, but our Paladin jumped in to all the cultist's surprise, while 5e might not technically have a surprise round, all of the enemies being surprised is in essence the same thing

Comment: @Bwash: I'm not trying to pick on you, but using correct terminology is important, not only for getting a good answer to your question, but also for ensuring that it is not confusing for people regardless of their D&D expertise. There is nothing wrong with having your post edited for reasons like this.

Comment: The [Help] article [“Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?”](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/editing) is a handy reference that's relevant to the comment thread, which may answer some questions about the site.

Comment: Thanks SevenSidedDie, but it's not the fact that people can edit my posts that bothers me, it's when they edit it when there was nothing wrong with the original post that bothers me

Comment: Also, there is a difference between a surprise round and enemies being surprised. If they are surprised, but roll a higher initiative than you, they would be able to use their reactions on your turn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHB p.195:

> You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction

Your enemy is being forced to move by you and he is not using his own movement, action or reaction, therefore he won't trigger an Opportunity Attack.

Comment: This makes me sad because it would've been a good tactic but rules are rules, thanks

Comment: Also the enemy is being knocked *into* the allies' reach not out of. So, that would not provide provoke an OA regardless.

Comment: @Bwash don't write it completely off. You can still ready an action so that when Bob the Barbarian knocks him toward you, you shove him off the cliff.